# Why not to inherit from std::allocator

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I created my own allocator like so:

```
template<typename T>
class BasicAllocator
{
    public:
        typedef size_t size_type;
        typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
        typedef T* pointer;
        typedef const T* const_pointer;
        typedef T& reference;
        typedef const T& const_reference;
        typedef T value_type;


        BasicAllocator() throw() {};
        BasicAllocator (const BasicAllocator& other) throw() {};

        template<typename U>
        BasicAllocator (const BasicAllocator<U>& other) throw() {};

        template<typename U>
        BasicAllocator& operator = (const BasicAllocator<U>& other) {return *this;}
        BasicAllocator<T>& operator = (const BasicAllocator& other) {return *this;}
        ~BasicAllocator() {}

        pointer address (reference value) const {return &value;}
        const_pointer address (const_reference value) const {return &value;}

        pointer allocate (size_type n, const void* hint = 0) {return static_cast<pointer> (::operator new (n * sizeof (value_type) ) );}
        void deallocate (void* ptr, size_type n) {::operator delete (static_cast<T*> (ptr) );}

        template<typename U, typename... Args>
        void construct (U* ptr, Args&&  ... args) {::new (static_cast<void*> (ptr) ) U (std::forward<Args> (args)...);}
        void construct (pointer ptr, const T& val) {new (static_cast<T*> (ptr) ) T (val);}

        template<typename U>
        void destroy (U* ptr) {ptr->~U();}
        void destroy (pointer ptr) {ptr->~T();}

        size_type max_size() const {return std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof (T);} /**return std::size_t(-1);**/

        template<typename U>
        struct rebind
        {
            typedef BasicAllocator<U> other;
        };
};
```

But I want to know why I should never inherit from `std::allocator`. Is it because it doesn't have a virtual destructor? I've seen many posts saying that one should create their own and not inherit. I understand why we shouldn't inherit `std::string` and `std::vector` but what is wrong with inheriting `std::allocator`?

Can I inherit my class above? Or do I need a virtual destructor to do that?

Why?

Comment: `new (static_cast<T*> (ptr) )` looks like a typo (the function is already taking a `pointer == T*`)

Comment: It's perfectly OK to inherit after `std::vector` or `std::string`. You can do this safely with private or protected inheritance and then expose desired part of their interface with `using` keyword.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A lot of people are going to post in this thread that you should not inherit from `std::allocator` because it doesn't have a virtual destructor. They'll talk about polymorphism and slicing and deleting via pointer-to-base class, none of which are permitted by the allocator requirements as detailed in section 17.6.3.5 [allocator.requirements] of the standard. Until someone demonstrates that a class derived from `std::allocator` fails to meet one of those requirements, it's simple cargo cult mentality.

That said, there is little reason to derive from `std::allocator` in C++11. C++11's overhaul of allocators introduced the traits template [`std::allocator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) to sit between an allocator and its users and provide reasonable defaults for many of the required features via template metaprogramming. [A minimal allocator in C++11 can be as simple as:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9214894a7c7a921d)

```
template <typename T>
struct mallocator {
  using value_type = T;

  mallocator() = default;
  template <class U>
  mallocator(const mallocator<U>&) {}

  T* allocate(std::size_t n) {
    std::cout << "allocate(" << n << ") = ";
    if (n <= std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(T)) {
      if (auto ptr = std::malloc(n * sizeof(T))) {
        return static_cast<T*>(ptr);
      }
    }
    throw std::bad_alloc();
  }
  void deallocate(T* ptr, std::size_t n) {
    std::free(ptr);
  }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator == (const mallocator<T>&, const mallocator<U>&) {
  return true;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator != (const mallocator<T>& a, const mallocator<U>& b) {
  return !(a == b);
}
```

EDIT: Proper use of `std::allocator_traits` isn't fully present in all standard libraries yet. For example, the sample allocator above doesn't work correctly with `std::list` when compiled with GCC 4.8.1 - the `std::list` code complains about missing members since it hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: I like this! Did not know I could do what you have there without explicitly creating every member I have in my allocator. Thank you for this! I thought I'd have to implement allocator_traits some how. I wasn't aware that the containers used it. =)  This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: For your info, tried std::list<int, my_allocator<int>> on clang with libc++ and clang's own c++abi, and compiled fine.

Comment: @user534498 libc++ was never intended to support language versions earlier than C++11, so I'm not surprised it's further along in allocator_traits support than libstdc++. Thanks for the verification.

Comment: In practice I found GCC 5.3 did not call my custom `deallocate(pointer, size_type)` when inheriting from `std::allocator`. It was the only member function provided in the derived class. I also verified it was not the optimizer by testing with `-O0`.

Comment: Well, a potential reason to derive from `std::allocator` would be the need to instrument it's behaviour. In such case, one could want to log some data, then the default behaviour on `allocate` and `deallocate`. In such cases, public inheritance seems like an easy approach, with the benefit that `std::iterator_trait` would still be able to rely on the public API from `std::allocator`.

Comment: Cargo cultist here about §1… though the rest of the answer is good. Slicing/non-virtual polym. delete are problems that occur when the dynamic type differs from the static type, and the requirements do not even mention the dynamic type. Hence, compliant code could be broken by giving it ptrs/refs to `std::allocator<T>` which really point to another type. Of course the conversion is a very bad idea and probably forbidden, but the compiler is "nice" enough to do it implicitly whenever it helps to make the code compile. "An interface should be easy to use, hard to misuse." – Scott Meyers, I think

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why the OPs allocator doesn't allocate. He doesn't inherit from `std::allocator`. One ought to be able to create its own complete allocator without any "help" from `std::allocator_traits`.

Answer (score 6):

The class template `std::allocator<...>` doesn't have any virtual functions. Thus, it is clearly a bad candidate to provide derived functionality. While some classes or class templates are still reasonable base classes, even without a virtual destructor and any other virtual function, these tend to be either just tag types or use the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Allocators are not intended to be customized like that, i.e., `std::allocator<T>` isn't intended as a base class. If you tried to use it as such, your logic may easily end up being sliced off. The approach used for easy customization of allocators is to rely on `std::allocator_traits<A>` to provide the various operations your allocator choose not to provide explicitly using a default implementation based on a relatively small number of operations.

The main issue about deriving from `std::allocator<T>` is that it may hide a problem with the `rebind` member, e.g., the member being omitted or misspelled. Below is an example which should print `my_allocator::allocate()` twice but doesn't due to a typo. I think `my_allocator<T>` is except for the typo a complete allocator even without the inheritance from `std::allocator<T>`, i.e., the unnecessary inheritance only contributes to the potential to hiding errors. You can also get an error, e.g., by getting the `allocate()` or `deallocate()` function wrong.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct my_allocator
    : std::allocator<T>
{
    my_allocator() {}
    template <typename U> my_allocator(my_allocator<U> const&) {}

    typedef T value_type;
    template <typename U> struct rebimd { typedef my_allocator<U> other; };
    T* allocate(size_t n) {
        std::cout << "my_allocator::allocate()\n";
        return static_cast<T*>(operator new(n*sizeof(T)));
    }
    void deallocate(T* p, size_t) { operator delete(p); }
};

template <typename A>
void f(A a)
{
    typedef std::allocator_traits<A>    traits;
    typedef typename traits::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename traits::pointer    pointer;
    pointer p = traits::allocate(a, sizeof(value_type));
    traits::deallocate(a, p, sizeof(value_type));

    typedef typename traits::template rebind_alloc<int> other;
    typedef std::allocator_traits<other> otraits;
    typedef typename otraits::value_type ovalue_type;
    typedef typename otraits::pointer    opointer;
    other o(a);
    opointer op = otraits::allocate(o, sizeof(ovalue_type));
    otraits::deallocate(o, op, sizeof(ovalue_type));
}

int main()
{
    f(my_allocator<int>());
}
```

Comment: I cannot find any examples of `std::allocator_traits` being used or what it is for. I also noticed that libraries are using an allocator similar to mine and inheriting from it without a virtual destructor. I read somewhere that an allocator should have no virtual functions.  http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2011-05/msg00120.html

Comment: Can you demonstrate which of the operations detailed in the allocator requirements (C++11 17.6.3.5) has the potential to slice off logic?

Comment: @Casey: sure. The obvious culprit is omitting or misspelling `rebind`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: "A requirement is optional if the last column of Table 28 specifies a default for a given expression." The proper way to rebind in C++11 is via allocator_traits: `typedef typename traits::template rebind_alloc<int> other;`. Or by rebinding the traits directly: `typedef typename traits::template rebind_traits<int> otraits; typedef typename otraits::allocator_type other;`

Comment: @Casey: thanks for pointing out the error. I have updated the example. It still has the problem. In fact, to fix the code all what is needed now is to remove the inheritance from `std::allocator<T>`.

Comment: +1 for typos being a source of silent errors - possibly the worse kind of error - when publicly inheriting. This is notably not an issue that virtual functions would prevent: there's no `override` for member templates, after all.

Comment: "Class does not have virtual functions". I don't buy this argument, especially since we have `final` keyword in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit an issue in VS2013 (but it doesn't appear in VS2015) about this. Probably not an answer to this question but I'm going to share this anyway:

In boost there is a function `call_select_on_container_copy_construction()` testing whether an allocator has a member `select_on_container_copy_construction()` and call that function to get a copy of the allocator. While the `std::allocator` returns a copy of itself, the derived `myallocator` should override this method to do the same and return `myallocator` type instead of leaving it to inherit the one with `std::allocator` return type. This result in compile error with unmatched types.

If `myallocator` inherits `std::allocator`, it has to override any parent method that may not have the same return type with the type when it is overridden.

Note, this only appear in VS2013 as far as I see so you may argue it's a problem with the compiler not the code.

The `myallocator` I used is `aligned_allocator` in Eigen since version 3.3.0.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the destructor [is not `virtual`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/~allocator). This is not a direct problem if you don't use the allocator polymorphically. But consider this case, where `BasicAllocator` inherits from `std::allocator`:

```
std::allocator<int>* ptr = new BasicAllocator<int>();
// ...
delete ptr;
```

The destructor of `BasicAllocator` is never called, leading to a memory leak.

Comment: No where in the standard's detailing of allocator requirements does it say that an allocator must support deletion through a pointer to one of its base classes. You present a good reason not to treat a class derived from another class without a virtual destructor polymorphically in general, but it does not answer the OP's question since it does not apply to the specific case of allocators.