# no conversion from "std::allocator" to "const allocator_type"

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang++, icc

I am trying to implement an aligned allocator for use with MKL in C++11. I have:

```
template <typename T, size_t TALIGN = 16, size_t TBLOCK = 4>
class aligned_allocator : public std::allocator<T>
{
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::size_type size_type;
public:
    pointer allocate(size_type n, const void *hint = nullptr);
    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n);
};
```

Elsewhere, I have:

```
template<typename T> using aligned_vector = std::vector<T, aligned_allocator<T>>;
```

and finally, I have this operator overload:

```
inline aligned_vector<double> operator+(aligned_vector<double> x, aligned_vector<double> y)
{
    aligned_vector<double> z(x.size());
    vdAdd(x.size(), x.data(), y.data(), z.data());
    return z;
}
```

This all compiles and works perfectly under both `icc` and `clang`, but with GCC 4.9, it won't compile unless I make `x` and `y` both const-references. Why does GCC require this when the others don't?

Comment: Where is your `rebind`?

Comment: @Cubbi: `rebind` isn't needed in C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `rebind`:

```
template <typename U> struct rebind { typedef aligned_allocator<U> other; };
```

That said, you shouldn't inherit from `std::allocator`: [Why not to inherit from std::allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081796/why-not-to-inherit-from-stdallocator)

Comment: Wow, that was quick - and the solution! Thanks!

Comment: But why does it work in clang, and icc, but not gcc? (this was my question)

Comment: @AlexReinking clang 3.4.1 and icc 13.0.1 both require `rebind` for me: http://goo.gl/Cgu1oF

Comment: Ah, it seems that icc 14.0.3 does not for me.

Comment: @AlexReinking: GCC's libstdc++ is far from C++11 compliant. Most of the containers do not implement containers in terms of C++11's allocator requirements.