# How to modernize allocator-adapter for VC++17/20

Tags: c++, std, allocator, c++17, c++20

I have an allocator-adapter that I call `ctor_allocator`. I wrote it more for experimentation than for any actual need.  It adapts an allocator to use default construction when feasible, thus bypassing any default initialization by assignment. E.g., construction of a vector of doubles will not initialize the values to 0.0 (or to anything).

A lot of the code in the adapter is old fashion, and, it would appear, might be deprecated soon if not already. I have not as yet succeeded in modernizing the code without defeating the purpose of it. For example, if I remove the `struct rebind` template, the zero-initialization returns.

**Can you show how to modernize it?**

An answer would probably prove instructive for other applications.

**Edit:** In the comments, Brandon gave these two links as examples of "the new way". [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081796) and [Minimal example](http://ideone.com/40WpQc).  Neither prevents the initialization with zeros, which happens in `construct`. However, if I modify either example  by adding the `void construct(U* ptr)` template, the zero-initialization is averted.  That answers a different question than I am asking here, but it's a good answer to a good question.

```
#include <memory>   
namespace dj {
    template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
    class ctor_allocator : public A
    {
        using a_t = std::allocator_traits<A>;
    public:
        using A::A; // Inherit constructors from A
        template <typename U>
        struct rebind {
            using other  = ctor_allocator<U, typename a_t::template rebind_alloc<U>>;
        };

        template <typename U>
        void construct(U* ptr)
            noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<U>::value)
        {
            ::new(static_cast<void*>(ptr)) U;
        }

        template <typename U, typename...Args>
        void construct(U* ptr, Args&&... args) {
            a_t::construct(static_cast<A&>(*this),
                ptr, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    };
}

// Test case. main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
using vector = std::vector<T, dj::ctor_allocator<T>>;

int main() {
    {
        vector<int> v(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            v[i] = i * 56313;
        }
    }
    // If ctor_allocator works as intended, 
    // this probably will not print all zeros.
    vector<int> v(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        std::cout << std::hex << v[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You don't **"need"** to inherit `std::allocator`. You can always just let `std::allocator_traits` do the work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081796/why-not-to-inherit-from-stdallocator  Minimal allocator could be: https://ideone.com/40WpQc

Comment: @Brandon - Thanks. I will peruse the answer.

Comment: @Brandon - That's good info. I can modify either example to side-step the initialization to zeros by adding the `void construct(U* ptr)` template to them.  That answers a different question than I asked, but it's a good answer to a good question.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to hints from Brandon, I figgered it out - at least most of it. A possible solution is delegate `allocate` and `deallocate` to the base-class, rather than inheriting from it.  On VC++2017 at least, I still need to specialize `construct`, although I have seen documentation to the effect that the specialization I supply is precisely what the default should be.

The following might need some copy-constructor and assignment-operator stuff. Please advise.

```
#include <memory>

namespace dj {  

template<typename T, typename Base = std::allocator<T>>
struct ctor_allocator 
    {           
        Base A;
        using value_type = typename Base::value_type;
        using pointer = typename Base::pointer;

        pointer allocate(std::size_t n, const void* hint = 0)
        {
            auto ret = A.allocate(n,hint);
            return ret;
        }

        void deallocate(pointer ptr, std::size_t n)
        {
            A.deallocate(ptr, n);
        }

        template <typename U >
        void construct(U* ptr) {
                ::new (ptr) U;
        }   
    };

template <typename T, typename U>
    inline 
    bool operator==(const ctor_allocator<T>& left, const ctor_allocator<U>& right) 
        {
            return left.A == right.A;
        }

template <typename T, typename U>
    inline bool operator != (const ctor_allocator<T>& a, const ctor_allocator<U>& b) 
        {
            return !(a == b);
        }
}

// MAIN.cpp
#include <vector>
template<class T>
using vector = std::vector<T, dj::ctor_allocator<T>>;

int main() {
    {
        vector<int> v(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        v[i] = i * 313;
        }
    }
    vector<int> v(20);
    for (auto i: v) {
        std::cout << std::hex << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "*I have seen documentation to the effect that the specialization I supply is precisely what the default should be.*" The default would be `::new (ptr) U();`. Indeed, the change you're seeking comes from the difference between default-initialization and value-initialization.