# Custom deallocator with an std::vector doesn't get called

Tags: c++, allocation, allocator

I am expecting this code to print "Hello world" - "Hello " when the memory is deallocated and "world" in `main`. However "Hello" never gets printed, meaning that my deallocator doesn't get called. What's the proper way to implement it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class MyAllocator : public std::allocator<uint8_t>
{
public:
  void deallocate(uint8_t* data, std::size_t size)
  {
    std::cout << "Hello ";
    std::allocator<uint8_t>::deallocate(data, size);
  }
};


int main()
{
  {
    std::vector<uint8_t, MyAllocator> v(100);
  }
  std::cout << "world\n";

  return 0;
}
```

I assume it just calls the default `std::allocator<uint8_t>::deallocate()` function, but I am not seeing a way to prevent it and make it call my function.

Comment: Try not to say "doesn't work", that isn't a meaningful diagnostic. I've adjusted the title to better reflect your question.

Comment: I think making a custom allocator is a bit more involved than that, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081796/why-not-to-inherit-from-stdallocator#21083096

Comment: I don't really see a conceptual difference between their allocator and mine. Sure, theirs has templates and a couple more constructors defined, but if std::vector needed to call something that my class is missing, it wouldn't compile. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact your allocator will work if you define rebind:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class MyAllocator : public std::allocator<uint8_t>
{
public:

    template <typename U>
    struct rebind
    {
        typedef MyAllocator other;
    };

    void deallocate(uint8_t* data, std::size_t size)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello ";
        std::allocator<uint8_t>::deallocate(data, size);
    }
};


int main()
{
  {
    std::vector<uint8_t, MyAllocator> v(100);
  }
  std::cout << "world\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Produces:

> Hello world

Comment: Works for gcc, but in VS I get an error: `Error C2664 'void std::_Deallocate_plain<MyAllocator,0>(_Alloc &,unsigned char *const )': cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::_Container_proxy *' to 'unsigned char *const ' HelloTest c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\vector 557 
`

Comment: It compiles fine with VS 2017  / ISO C++17 Standard.           (`\std::c++17`)

Answer (score 1):

`std::allocator` defines the member `template rebind<U>`.
Alternatives not of the form `AllocatorType<ValueType, Args...>` must do so too.

And `std::vector` properly uses it to make sure it allocates the right chunks of memory, with the appropriate size and alignment, so even though you passed your custom allocator, the rebinding results in actually using the standard allocator.

See for example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator for the potential members of an allocator.

Comment: Its stupid that one must define rebind. And CppReference isnt kind enough to point this out.

Comment: Actually, it does point it out. When it is optional is a bit hidden though.