# Custom allocator not been used

Tags: c++, allocator

Consider the following code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyAlloc : public std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::string>>
{
public:
    MyAlloc()
    {
        std::cout << "my alloc ctor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, MyAlloc> ms;
    ms.insert(std::make_pair(2, "hi"));
    std::cout << ms[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've created my allocator to fit the default one. But I see my allocator not been used, not even constructed.

when I'm using a debugger I can see the `map` is using the default `std::allocator`.

Is there any problem with my allocator?

Comment: Maybe look over [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081796/why-not-to-inherit-from-stdallocator)?

Comment: @AlexLarionov It doesn't answer why the `map` letting me define an allocator but use another.

Comment: *"the map is using the default std::allocator"* - Did you pay attention to the argument it used for `std::allocator`? If I was a betting man I'd wager it's not using `std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::string>>`, but `std::allocator<_SomeNodeType>`

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I just don't get it, why does the map 4th template argument never been used nor even created.

Comment: It's used alright, just not in a way you expect. It's fed into `std::allocator_traits` to obtain things the standard library implentation needs. Persumably it's the allocator type being rebound (you did not customize how it happens) that's throwing you off.